# Side effects of calling RegisterWindow multiple times with same window class?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a little test application at the minute and I have multiple window objects floating around and they each call RegisterWindowEx with the same WNDCLASSEX structure (mainly because they are all an instance of the same class).

The first one registers ok, then multiple ones fail, saying class already registered - as expected.

My question is - is this bad? I was thinking of using a hash table to store the ATOM results in, to look up before calling RegisterWindow, but it seems Windows does this already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test if the window class was previously registered calling **GetClassInfoEx**.

> If the function finds a matching class
>   and successfully copies the data, the
>   return value is nonzero.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633579(VS.85).aspx

This way you can conditionally register the window class based on the return of **GetClassInfoEx**.

Comment: You'd need to be careful to avoid multi-threaded race conditions if you did it this way. I.e. lock around the calls to GetClassInfoEx and RegisterWindowEx to prevent a call to UnregisterClass() occurring between.

Answer (score 4):

### If your window class is defined in a DLL

Perhaps you should call your `RegisterClass()` in the PROCESS_ATTACH part of the DllMain, and call your `UnregisterClass()` in the PROCESS_DETACH part of the DllMain

### If your window class is defined in the executable

Perhaps you should call your `RegisterClass()` in the main, before the message loop, and call your `UnregisterClass()` in the main, after the message loop.

### Registering in an object constructor would be a mistake

Because you would, by reflex, clean it in the destructor. Should one of your window be destroyed, the destructor will be called and... If you have other windows floating around...

And using global data to count the number of active registration will need proper synchronisation to be sure your code is thread-friendly, if not thread-safe.

### Why in the main/DllMain?

Because you're registering some kind of global object (at least, for your process). So it makes sense to have it initialized in a "global way", that is either in the main or in the DllMain.

### Why it is not so evil?

Because Windows will not fail just because you did register it more than once.

A clean code would have used `GetClassInfo()` to ask if the class was already registered.

But again, Windows won't crash (for this reason, at least).

You can even avoid unregistering the window class, as Windows will clean them away when the process will end. I saw conflicting info on MSDN blogs on the subject (two years ago... don't ask me to find the info again).

### Why it is evil anyway?

My personal viewpoint is that you should cleanly handle your resources, that is allocate them once, and deallocate them once. Just because Win32 will clean leaking memory should not stop you from freeing your dynamically allocated memory. The same goes for window classes.

Comment: RegisterClassEx() the main/DllMain - May not be CLEAN way.
Since RegisterClassEx() resides in User32.dll. From what I know it is safe to use only functions from kernel32.dll functions inside DllMain(). Please advise.

Comment: I never realized that a registered window takes up much memory. I know that Bitmaps take up good amount of memory.

Comment: Why do people insist that you manually free memory in C++; even though the memory is guaranteed to be freed automatically? Are they trying to give C++ a bad name.

Comment: @user13947194 The RegisterClass() and UnregisterClass() functions are for the purpose of win32's window class/object paradigm, not to be confused with the OOP paradigm of C++. You can have multiple windows(objects) all of the same class that behave a certain way as defined by the class. Although there is some memory associated with the class, the registration is not strictly for memory management.

The OS manages the window classes and automatically unregisters them when the process ends. C++ absolutely does not guarantee memory will be freed automatically, and leaks can cause crashes.

Comment: @vishayp C++is not responsible for freeing Windows memory. But the fact is we are using Cpp to write Windows Application as such; people assume we must manually free the memory. If it were Java they would assume memory was free automatically. Even std iofstream people are recommended to manually call close. But the destructor calls close as part of its destroying the iofstream.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to call RegisterWindowEx once and then use the resulting ATOM when you create your windows. There are no problems in reusing this ATOM for several windows.

Comment: this is a very mean and lean way. Alas that's what the atoms are for.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently. To get around it and keep all of the code in the class concerned rather than spreading it around the program I had a class static reference count that I incremented before calling RegisterClass(). I then ignored return values of ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS and only called UnregisterClass() in the dtor when the reference count was 0.

This didn't require any locking (use InterlockedIncrement() and InterlockedDecrement() to manage the reference count) and means that uses of the class don't need to know or care that internally the class uses a hidden window.

Comment: Not documented on MSDN RegisterClass() but I think I like your answer best. Minus the decrement/ UnregisterClass part as Windows will free this Memory for you. But your answer seems more efficient than calling GetClassInfo. In either case we must allocate a WNDCLASS. In either case it will get filled out. In either case Windows will have to search its database to see if the class is already registered. But using GetClassInfo and then RegisterWindow will cause this to be done TWICE. In regards to other answer; I am running away from making local static ATOM variables that exist forever.

Comment: I always like code to clean up after itself, hence the decrement and unregister. I find that it makes it easier to unit test the code if, once it's gone, everything is as if it had never been.

Comment: so be it. but don't tell people Cpp is hard because you must manually free your resources.

Comment: Cpp isn't hard, it's glorious :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might be able to avoid a call down into the kernel - RegisterClass seems to need to get down there - but window classes are per-process and per-module, so you shouldn't hurt anything by registering a class multiple times.

Given that there aren't generally that many classes, I wouldn't be too surprised to find it was actually implemented as a linked-list. You might get a little gain by looking it up in a hash table, but you'd probably be better off doing it as a simple boolean.